# Can't change repo in discourse docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, discourse

I want to make modification to the appearance of [discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/) by plugin.
Due to the plugin architecture I have to fork repos.

First I changed repo in [discourse_docker](https://github.com/sevenmaxis/discourse_docker/commit/793b33b36fb627b42946c79f2ecb89a4f64e5900) at my forked [discourse_docker](https://github.com/sevenmaxis/discourse_docker)

Then I forked [discourse](https://github.com/sevenmaxis/discourse) itself, add some [change](https://github.com/sevenmaxis/discourse/commit/46c7f6ece856c12a67dd06747731d9b3f1c56ca1) to test.
Went to my in [instance](http://37.48.87.4/), checked Dockerfile - it had link to my repo, installed all by instruction, build an app, enter that app and check 
`git remote show origin` - it didn't change:

```
Fetch URL: https://github.com/discourse/discourse.git
```

I've tried to remove images and rebuild them, same result

What am I missing here?

It seems that it doesn't build image from that Docker, how to force to build this one?

Answer (score 0):

Something worthful useful for you I have found. Hopes it works for you.

https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker[Click](https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker)

Comment: Actually I forked from this repo